# The tag wiki for [octodad] implies it should be [octodad-dadliest-catch] instead

Tags: support, tag-wiki

All three questions with the [octodad](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/octodad) tag appear to be about the newly-released sequel, Octodad: Dadliest Catch, and not about the original game that came about as a school project. Even the *tag wiki* describes Dadliest Catch.

Whether or not anybody (other than the user who made the tag) actually refers to Dadliest Catch without the subtitle, I think the tag as it is currently used should be renamed to [octodad-dadliest-catch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/octodad-dadliest-catch) so that [octodad](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/octodad) can be used for questions about the original game should any such questions surface in the future.

I can retag the questions myself easily<sup>1</sup>, but what about the tag wiki: do I simply create the wiki for the new tag name and paste the content there? Do I need to rewrite the wiki for the original game tag, or would doing that now be futile once the tag is no longer used on any questions (e.g. would the wiki be orphaned, or deleted entirely, etc)?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>In fact, [I did do just that](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/153148/revisions), but realized the wiki wouldn't be migrated over so I rolled it back first to preserve the wiki.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I am aware, if the tag isn't on any questions after they are retagged with the tag that is for the actual game, it will naturally disappear after a certain amount of time. If there is a tag wiki for the old tag, that actually describes the game that people are talking about (Dadliest Catch), then using it for the proper tag makes sense to me, as, well, it is the correct content, just in the wrong place.

Using the full name of the game in this case makes sense, and it fits as a tag without running into character count issues, so I think the retag makes sense, just so that we don't end up confusing people unnecessarily.

Comment: All the privileges/restrictions apply when moving the wiki to the new tag, right?

Comment: I wouldn't see why not.

Comment: I'll do it anyway. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with the separation of the two tags.  Really, the only reason it wasn't already that way is because there are no Octodad questions on Arquade.  But using the proper game name makes more sense.